# How to increase color resolution in python matplotlib colormap

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

I am making a colormap of a 2D numpy meshgrid:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(fields, frequencies)
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, fields_freqs_abs_grid, cmap="viridis", N=256)
```

The values in fields_freqs_abs_grid, which are plotted by color, have already been logarithmically scaled.

The colormap produced by python's matplotlib is coarse -- it scales over 8 colors even though I use "N=256" for the number of RGB pixels. Increasing N to 2048 did not change anything. A plot using the MatLab language on the same data produces a colormap with significantly higher color resolution. How do I increase the number of colors mapped in Python?

The result is: [image]

But I want the result to be: [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `imshow` instead of `contourf`.  Use the `extent` argument to set the x and y axis ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Warren Weckesser's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836348/how-to-increase-color-resolution-in-python-matplotlib-colormap/#comments-44836348) definitely works and can give you a high resolution image. I implemented his idea in the example below.

In regarding to use `contourf()`, I'm not sure if this is a version dependent issue, but in the most recent version,
 [`contourf()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html) doesn't have a kwarg for `N`.

As you can see in the document, you want to use `N` as an arg (in syntax: `contourf(X,Y,Z,N)`) to specify how many levels you want to plot rather than the number of RGB pixels. `contourf()` draws filled contours and the resolution depends on the number of levels to draw. Your `N=256` won't do anything and `contourf()` will automatically choose [7 levels](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/contour.py#L1151).

The following code is modified from the official [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html), comparing resolutions with different `N`. In case there is a version issue, this code gives the following plot with `python 3.5.2; matplotlib 1.5.3`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10 * (Z1 - Z2)

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)

# Your code sample
CS1 = ax1.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap="viridis", N=256)
ax1.set_title('Your code sample')
ax1.set_xlabel('word length anomaly')
ax1.set_ylabel('sentence length anomaly')
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(CS1, ax=ax1)

# Contour up to N=7 automatically-chosen levels, 
# which should give the same as your code.
N = 7
CS2 = ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, N, cmap="viridis")
ax2.set_title('N=7')
ax2.set_xlabel('word length anomaly')
ax2.set_ylabel('sentence length anomaly')
cbar2 = fig.colorbar(CS2, ax=ax2)

# Contour up to N=100 automatically-chosen levels.
# The resolution is still not as high as using imshow().
N = 100
CS3 = ax3.contourf(X, Y, Z, N, cmap="viridis")
ax3.set_title('N=100')
ax3.set_xlabel('word length anomaly')
ax3.set_ylabel('sentence length anomaly')
cbar3 = fig.colorbar(CS3, ax=ax3)

IM = ax4.imshow(Z, cmap="viridis", origin='lower', extent=(-3, 3, -3, 3))
ax4.set_title("Warren Weckesser's idea")
ax4.set_xlabel('word length anomaly')
ax4.set_ylabel('sentence length anomaly')
cbar4 = fig.colorbar(IM, ax=ax4)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]