# How to increase color resolution in python matplotlib 3D plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, 3d

(edited to make the code clearer) I am using Poly3DCollection to make a graph where several polygons in a 3D space have a colour that depends on a value contained in a separate array.

```
cmap = cm.plasma
quantity = [0.1, 0.11, 5, 10]
colours = cmap(quantity)
    
for i in range(K):
    x = [0, 1, 1, 0]
    y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    z = [0, 1, 0, 1]
    verts = [list(zip(x, y, z))]     
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(verts, color=colours[i]))
```

the problem I have is that the resulting image has a very limited colour resolution, and most of the polygons have the same colours.

I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836348/how-to-increase-color-resolution-in-python-matplotlib-colormap) that it may depend from python automatically using only 7 different colour levels, but unfortunately the solution in the post only applies to 2D plots.

Any idea on how to extend that to 3D plots?

Comment: Why do you use `colours[i,:]` and not `colours[:]`? Or what is `K`? You need to provide a [mcve] for anyone to know what goes wrong in your case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited the sample code and corrected the typo, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: You create K times the same polygon, each with a different color. But since they are all on top of each other you only see one color (the topmost).

Comment: Actually in the real example the polygons have different vertices, I have oversimplified. The problem is that instead of having 4 different shades of the spectrum I only see 3, the small color differences are not shown

Comment: Note that 5 and 10 are outside [0,1], so they get the same color

Comment: Shouldn't `colours = cmap(quantity)` take care of that and map `quantity` into the plasma palette?

Comment: A matplotlib colormap maps values between 0.0 and 1.0 to a color.